# With NSIS can I share values between MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY pages?

Tags: nsis, nsis-mui

I have two MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY pages.  The first stores the entered data to the default, $INSTDIR.  What I would like to do is copy the value in $INSTDIR to the defined var $DataDir so that before the second directory page is displayed, $DataDir becomes $INSTDIR\Data.  When the second page is displayed I would like the default value to be $INSTDIR\Data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InstallDir $ProgramFiles\MyApp

Var DataDir
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE InstDirPageLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE $DataDir
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Choose Data directory for bla bla bla..."
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "Data Directory:"
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW DataDirShowPage
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function InstDirPageLeave
StrCpy $DataDir "$InstDir\Data"
FunctionEnd

Function DataDirShowPage
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Foo" "Bar"
FunctionEnd

Section
DetailPrint $InstDir
DetailPrint $DataDir
SectionEnd
```

Comment: The macro MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE was what I needed.

Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve?

If you want to install some files into two **separate** locations use MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY and custom nsDialogs page (with browse folder button) so user can pick up two directories.

If your location is always $INSTDIR and second is somewhere inside it ($INSTDIR\some\data\path) then you only need to append your inside path to $INSTDIR - there is no need to show dialog twice and select path twice.